# Textarea caret-color not working for iOS safari browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, safari

I wanted to hide text cursor(caret) from textarea,
I tried by using `caret-color` property but its not working for iOS browsers (tried safari and chrome both).

Is there any other way to achieve it?

here is a way I tried

```
.disabled_caret {
    caret-color: transparent;
}
```

JS code:

```
input.addClass('disabled_caret');
```

where input is a $('textarea')

Note: Its working fine for Android devices and desktop browsers

Answer (score 0):

I think there is nothing to do, I see in [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-caret-color) is not widely supported so if you don't have a newer iOS version you can't with only the CSS, so appear the default (black color)

Comment: I also tried newer iOS version , its not working for it as well.

Comment: Strange, try open

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/caret-color

i've tried with my iphone ios13.x and it works